# Modularising Layout/Views in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

In my code i'm using and XML file for showing a view in Android. The file is as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText 
        android:text="Search Box" 
        android:id="@+id/EditText01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"/>



</LinearLayout>


<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/ListView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

I'm a part of a multi member team, and the situation is that the code for the **EditText** and **ListView** will be written by 2 different developers in 2 different XML files. Then we will use **import** statements to import the code from these 2 XML files into the main XML file.

The problem is that we would like to give custom heights, widths and weights to the **EditText** and **ListView** in the main XML file only and not in their individual files. (Basically we want to set the layout of different elements in the main file, so that we can create any element like an EditText in a seperate XML file, import it into the main XML file, and then postion it at will on the screen)

Is this possible? If yes, then how can it be done?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say you would want to define [a style](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)?

From that page:

For example, by using a style, you can take this layout XML:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#00FF00"
    android:typeface="monospace"
    android:text="@string/hello" />
```

And turn it into this:

```
<TextView
    style="@style/CodeFont"
    android:text="@string/hello" />
```

You have one place where the style is (maybe main.xml isn't the best place for that, but I think your goal would be met even with a separate style file?)